# mac terminal: `open -a ` doesn't work, Unable to find application named

Tags: macos, shell

After my mac shutdown by accident once, the terminal commend `open -a`  doesn't work anywork. ( It's ok before that).

```
(base) ➜  tmp  $ open -a TextEdit .                                                                                                                                   [10:19:09]
Unable to find application named 'TextEdit'
(base) ➜  tmp  $ open -a textEdit ./livephoto.log                                                                                                                     [10:20:51]
Unable to find application named 'textEdit'
(base) ➜  tmp  $ open -a "Google Chrome"                                                                                                                              [10:21:17]
Unable to find application named 'Google Chrome'
(base) ➜  tmp  $ open -a "Safari"                                                                                                                                     [10:22:58]
Unable to find application named 'Safari'
```

What happend to it? How do I fix it?

Comment: But you still can start the applications manullly, from the desktop? How about via the Finder, i.e. double-clicking livephoto.log in the Finder?

Answer (score 1):

The LaunchServices may require a rebuilding...  The typical command is `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain u -domain s -domain l -v`

Comment: Thanks a ton. Had an app that used to work with `open -a` but suddenly stopped and gave `Unable to find application named`... this fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

The app can be opened by finder.
Finally I found it's zsh bug. It still work in the terminal.app.